# How to install (L|M)AMP stack on iPhone?

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, apache

I have a jailbroken iPhone 4 running iOS 4.3.3 upon which I want to run Apache, MySQL, and PHP. All of the information I've found is hopelessly out of date.

Are there packages I can install through Cydia or apt-get for this?

Any prodding in the right direction is much appreciated!

Comment: Why would you want to run a web and a database server on your iPhone?

Comment: Maybe he's trying to run an 3v1l w@r3z site off his 3g plan? :-D

Comment: impossible unless someone ports all 3 packages to native mac c

Comment: The sort of prodding i would render on a question like this almost certainly would not be appreciated!

Comment: @Codo I am a web developer and would like to be able to run my software without having to rely on connectivity and a remote server.

Comment: @Lawrence Thanks. Is there a better place to ask whether anyone has done this? I have read that Apache was ported at one point (but all the links I've found are dead.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there are people who tried this - http://www.ipadforums.net/ipad-hacking/24007-running-php-server-ipad.html
 and http://claytond.com/2007/11/07/an-iphone-powered-apache-web-server-with-php/

But I don't see mysql, also read comments some reported that preg_match wasn't working. Could be handy, but you gotta run all your tests before unleashing the power :)

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll toss my existing PHP framework and use Javascript with Web SQL Database.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Cydia solution: [lighttpd/php/mysql web stack](http://code.google.com/p/cydia-ios-lighttpd-php-mysql-web-stack/wiki/Main).