# Is an iAMP setup possible?

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, apache

I'd like to get apache, mysql, and php running in an iphone app. This is because I'm finding objective c to be quite difficult, and if I can get those three running and figure out how to set up a full-page browser or something, I can code my app like that.

The MySQL aspect isn't really a necessity since I can very easily code a flat file database in php for this.

Is this possible? Has it been done? If not, what frameworks should I use to make creating an app easier?

Comment: You can't use PHP on iOS devices, as it violates Apple's terms.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001186/how-to-install-lmamp-stack-on-iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming what you are saying is that you are more familiar with HTML and JavaScript, and would like to code with those tools.

If so, take a look at PhoneGap and Titanium. They are frameworks to code iOS apps with web technologies. Basically, it is like running a local file in a web browser (with interfaces to access device functions such as the GPS). No need to have a PHP and Apache stack there.

There is also a quasi-standard to write web applications that can work offline once downloaded. Mobile Safari supports this, and it can almost look like a native app.

Comment: PHP is a necessity for this, sorry. So no phonegap or titanium dev. What about other solutions? Are there any other IDEs other than XCode which can support different languages other than objective c, or make it easier at all?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for *any* other options, there's [Mono Touch](http://monotouch.net/), which is C# for iPhone.  It's garbage collected, managed, strongly typed, and has access to all the device functions just like PhoneGap.

There's not really any *simple* way to get PHP running on an iPhone.  You could try to get it to compile yourself, but that sounds like you'd be spending more time trying to get the framework working rather than working on your actual project.

Comment: Roll your own?  You _could_ try to get the PHP preprocessor running.  After all, you _can_ run basic C and C++ code on iOS.